# How to remove noise in binary image of natural scene text detection using OpenCV Python?

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, ocr, opencv, python

This is my binary image:
[input binary image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvpKr.jpg)

I'm trying to isolate the digits from all of the other stuff from the image. I got this output after applying stroke width transform to a runner with a bib.
I already tried using morphological transformations to close the holes of the digits and check the area of each contour then disregard those with a contour less than the average size. However, in this case, using the contour area to determine the noise is not useful because the noise is bigger than the characters.
Do you have any suggestions on how I can do it? Big thanks.

Comment: OpenCV have a thinning algorithm implemented in the `ximgproc` module.
It process a skeletonization so it reduce the numbers to the fewest number of pixel possible for each region.
Then you can take a look to the module `text` of OpenCV

Answer (score 0):

- You can try to use blur filter [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html)
- You can try to use [Dilate after Erode](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html).